# Estou utilizando de maneira correta a Tarefa Assíncrona?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async, assincronismo

Ola,

Estou fazendo um projeto em ASP.NET MVC e queria utilizar uma tarefa assincrona.
No meu repositorio eu tenho:

```
public async Task GerarItens(int codigo)
{ 
    using (var dbTran = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
         try
         {
              >> VARIOS SELECTs, UPDATEs, INSERTs <<
              dbTran.Commit;
              await Task.FromResult<object>(null);
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
              dbTran.Rollback();
              throw;
          }
     }
}
```

No meu controller eu tenho:

```
private async Task GeradorItens(int codigo)
{
    RepoExemplo repo = new RepoExemplo();
    await repo.GerarItens(codigo);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Listagem(int codigo)
{
    try
    {
        RepoExemplo repo = new RepoExemplo();

        await GeradorItens(codigo);

        return View(repo.Listar(codigo));
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return View("Error", ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

> Duvidas:
>
> 1. Posso utilizar o `dbTran` dentro de uma `async` `task`?
> 2. Quando que eu uso o `await`? No meu `GerarItens` do `Repositorio`, eu usaria em todos os meus `Selects`, `Inserts`, `Updates`?
>
>    2a. Se caso, exemplo, eu precisar fazer um `select` apos um `insert`, so que nesse `insert` eu colocar um `await`, eu vou ter o resultado certo no meu `select`?
>
>    2b. O que eu entendi sobre o assunto (falando bem leigamente), o `await` faz
>      a tarefa em segundo plano, portanto no meu exemplo se caso o `insert`
>      demorar pra ser feito, o meu `select` nao vai executar com as
>      informações que esse `insert` iria gerar, correto?
> 3. Quais as opções de retorno que eu tenho para uma metodo `TASK`? Eu usei o `await Task.FromResult<object>(null);` pois não sabia o que colocar...
> 4. `public async Task<ActionResult> Listagem`, é correto usar isso para o que eu estou querendo fazer?